# Revealing a 3rd party's IP / FQDN in a question

Tags: discussion, etiquette, privacy

I'm about to ask a question about some anomalous activity in my IIS logs.  Would it poor form to mention the IP addresses that I'm seeing the requests from?

They reverse lookup to what looks like home DSL addresses, and I don't believe the owners to be up to any malicious activity.

Answer (score 5):

Please, please, please include them. I'm sick of seeing ServerFault questions redacted for no good reason, it makes troubleshooting so much harder.

For example, when someone says "My web server, example.com, doesn't resolve to an IP address" - well, great, how about you tell us your real domain name so we can actually HELP rather than just bug you to provide more detail lest your question get closed!

Anyway, there's not really that much that can be achieved with a reverse dns lookup.

Comment: What I find extremely funny is when I see that people redact RFC1918 addresses.  The private addresses are not publicly accessible!  We can't do anything with them...

Answer (score 3):

> Would it poor form to mention the IP addresses that I'm seeing the requests from?

No, they are just numbers, and in the case of home DSL addresses they are relatively ephemeral anyway.

I suppose in specific situations where the users might have an expectation of privacy or confidentiality - for instance an AIDs testing website - then you might xxx.xxx.xxx.159 them out or something to obscure them, but if it's just a normal website with nothing special going on, I doubt it's going to be an issue.

Use your best judgment.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are not your IP addresses, it might be good to respect other peoples' privacy.  As an analogy; would you post peoples' home mailing addresses?  Probably not.  But, if knowing the specific IP addresses is necessary to answer the question, then perhaps.

Comment: Likewise, an IP address does not necessarily have just a single FQDN. And for shared web hosting, the different domains can be owned  by different people. (And when hacked, it might not even be the owners themselves who are misbehaving.) So: when trying to match an IP address to a domain, be sure you found the right domain if you're accusing someone of abuse.

Comment: I don't like the analogy - your IP address is always public. Expecting it to be private would be like having your phone number listed in the phone book, and then be surprised when people can look it up.

Comment: @Jared - excellent point, though I must say I would be a little confused to see a photo of the page with my phone number somewhere on the internet.

Comment: Maybe privacy is too strong a word. I don't have any expectation of privacy - but it would be great not to see my IP address posted somewhere public.  My home address might be in the book, but I'd rather it not show up in some random forum.  Just me.